# Как в tkinter реагировать на нажатие кнопки Закрыть?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, button

Как в **tkinter** реагировать на нажатие кнопки **Закрыть**? То есть когда пользователь в программе **tkinter** нажимает на кнопку **Закрыть**, необходимо чтобы **выполнялся** какой-то код. Для тех кто знаком с **PyGame** это что-то вроде этого кода:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        КАКОЙ-ТО КОД
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/111160/4794368

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


def on_closing():
    print("Выводится при попытке закрытия окна")
    root.destroy()  # Закрыть окно


root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
root.mainloop()
```

Основано на данном ответе: https://stackoverflow.com/a/111160 [@Matt Gregory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10577)

Answer (score -1):

```
done = False #создание переменной для выхода

while done == False: #создание игрового цикла(пока done==False игра будет работать)
    for e in pygame.event.get(): #перебор всех событий в игре
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True #обработка нажатия крестика в окне для выхода(обязательно один знак равно между done и True)
```

Comment: Вопрос не про pygame.

Comment: Вопрос не про PyGame, эта библиотека приведена только как пример